# Unexpected imaginary term in the asymptotic expansion of DawsonF

Tags: symbolic, special-functions, series-expansion

```
FullSimplify[Series[2 DawsonF[x], {x, ∞, 8}]]
(* -I Exp[-x^2] √π + (1/x + 1/(2 x^3) + 3/(4 x^5) + 15/(8 x^7) + O[1/x]^9) *)
```

What is the reason the term `-I Exp[-x^2] √π` is present here? The function being expanded is real-valued, and anyways the term decays faster than any of the polynomial terms given here, so why include it in the series, when I specified that I need terms up to the order 8?

The issue is reproducible both in version 8 and 10.2.

Comment: `FunctionExpand[DawsonF[x]]` probably gives a bit of a clue

Comment: To add to chuy's comment, note that the known asymptotic expansions for the imaginary error function (see e.g. the Wolfram Functions site) necessarily involve a complex term.

Comment: I still do not get it. Why there should be an imaginary term, if I'm interested in the asymptotic expansion when $x$ approaches the positive infinity along the real axis?